# New instance ignored

Tags: java, instance

Why do I receive a **"New instance ignored"** message with the following code?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Inferno infernogame= new Inferno();
    new Configuration(infernogame, appwidth, appheight,"Inferno....");
    new Thread(infernogame).start();      
}
```

Which calls:

```
public class Configuration 
{    
    public Configuration (Inferno application, int appwidth, int appheight, String apptitle){
        application.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        application.setResizable(false);
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        application.setTitle(apptitle);
        application.setSize(appwidth,appheight);
        application.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        application.setVisible(true);  
        application.setFocusable(true); 
        application.requestFocus();   
    }
}
```

Even though it still works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new Configuration(infernogame, appwidth, appheight,"Inferno....")`

You are creating a new Configuration instance, but you don't store it in a variable and don't do anything with it.

Since you keep no reference to that new instance, it will be eligible for garbage collection immediately.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to call a configuration class to configure my application at the beginning. JAVA does not have static classes so can you suggest how else this should / could be achieved?

Comment: @Munkybunky Convert it to a static method

Comment: @Munkybunky You can assign it to a variable. `Configuration config = new Configuration(infernogame, appwidth, appheight,"Inferno....");`

Comment: @Eran Now he would just get a unused warning.

Comment: @Frunk Well, if the code in the OP is the entire Configuration class, and it has no state, perhaps there shouldn't be a Configuration class at all. I agree with you that in this case it can be replaced with a static method called from the main method.

Comment: I am having something like that but the problem is that I DO store it somewhere. I dont understand. Inside the constructor this is what I do              main.getMapGeometries().put(id, this);

Answer (score 1):

The warning is because you are creating a new `Configuration` object and not doing anything with it in your code (for example assigning it to a variable so you cna use it later).

It's just a warning so you can ignore it, although your code is slightly unusual in that you normally don't create an instance of a class unless you intend to use it for something.